# Deploy high chart flexdashboard

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

I currently have a rmd page with high chart and flexdashboard. With database connect to provide data to the charts.

```
title: "ABC" 
output: 
     flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
         runtime: shiny 
         orientation: rows
         vertical_layout : scroll 
         theme: yeti 
         css: style.css 
runtime: shiny
```

How can I deploy this rmd page to eg. HTML while keeping the shiny. Currently I've tried rmarkdown::render() but for some reasons it doesn't connect to the dB and all the charts remain empty.

Comment: Sorry using phone to post. No idea how to format the code tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't you need to use `rmarkdown::run()` when it is interactive?

Comment: Can I run it from eg. linux console ? I'm trying to find a way to deploy it rather from just knit from my code

Comment: This is from the R console. If you have everything in your current working directory `rmarkdown::run()` should be enough. (see documentation). From the linux console you can do `Rscript -e 'rmarkdown::run()'`

Comment: I'm having a pandoc error. "Pandoc version 1.12.3 or higher is required and not found" any idea how to resolve ?